# Как убрать символ \u200b из строки php

Tags: php

При импорте данных(штрих-коды товаров) в таблицу MySQL в конце одной строки появляется символ \u200b Как его убрать? Сначала получаю данные из массива, потом пытаюсь их очистить от лишних символов, но этот символ остается

```
$EAN = trim(strval($node["data" . strval($index_EAN)]));
$EAN=str_replace('\u200b','',$EAN);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$EAN = preg_replace('/(\x{200e}|\x{200f})/u', '', $EAN)`

Comment: символ все равно остался

Comment: [`~\\u200b~u`](https://regex101.com/r/4L3E6D/2)

Comment: "~\\u200b~u" - это вставить в строку поиска? preg_replace('~\\u200b~u', '', $EAN)

Comment: если применить "~\\u200b~u" то удаляются вообще все штрих-коды

Comment: может это неправильное решение, но у меня сработало - скопировать красную точку(видна на скрине) и вставить между первыми кавычками в конструкцию str_replace('​','',$EAN);